# How to show javascript console output into an alert()

Tags: javascript, html, random, console

Everyday my teacher looks across the internet to find random facts for us then she writes on the board and we get to see it each day we go in her class. I'm trying to make a super simple website that once a button is clicked an alert at the top of the page appears. Whenever the fact I cant figure out how to make the console go to the alert. I've looked at a different other Stack question but i didn't really understand it. Here is my complete code. I'm sorry i just  started javascript and literally couldn't be more new to it. Thanks in advance!

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + "/facts.html");
});
const listener = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Your app is listening on port " + listener.address().port);
});

var fact = require('random-fact');
fact();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Generate Random Facts</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Fact Generator</h1>
<br><br><br><br>
<script>

function test() {
    alert('fact');
}

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Generate Random Fact!">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The JavaScript in your top box is node.js code that runs on the server. It can't alert in the browser.

Comment: Ohhh :(. Well it is possible to display in a box on the page?

Comment: Not with `console.log()`. You should use AJAX.

Comment: I have no idea what that is...Ummm is it easy?

Comment: Not if you're a total beginner.

Comment: Ohh. Welp i guess i give up on this then. Thanks though :(

Comment: This is fairly easy to do without AJAX, using templates instead (as I agree with Barmar you should understand client/server model before tackling AJAX). You'd replace your `sendFile` with rendering a template instead, with context containing a randomly picked fact. The button can be a simple form submit button that merely reloads the page, so no clientside JavaScript necessary. I suggest starting with MustacheExpress, since Mustache syntax is closest to HTML, and there are plenty of tutorials available.

Comment: I'm not nearly big brain enough for this 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like someone else said, the JavaScript you have up there is server side NodeJS.

Instead, just use your HTML and statically host it on GitHub or something.

Here is an example of a random fact from a list of facts:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Generate Random Facts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Fact Generator</h1>
        <p id="fact"> </p>
        <script>
            // populate with multiple facts
            var facts = ["fact one", "fact two", "fact three", "fact four"];

            function alertFact() {
                const fact = returnFact()
                
                document.getElementById('fact').innerText = fact
                alert(fact);
            }

            function returnFact() {
                var fact = facts[Math.floor(Math.random() * facts.length)];

                return fact;
            }
        </script>
        <input type="button" onclick="alertFact()" value="Generate Random Fact!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

or you can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/utdoLbj2/

Comment: Thanks much man! This works great. The only issue is i have to input each one my self but that's just because i'm a little lazy :D Right now i have 30 facts but soon i will have 3090 facts. LOL

Comment: What format are the facts in? You could pretty easily write a script to format them into the needed array.

Comment: That would be amazing! [this](https://github.com/assaf/dailyhi/blob/master/facts.txt) is the github with all the facts.

Comment: @moneymike here is the facts sorted into an array: 
https://github.com/mr-winson/so-helper/blob/master/facts/facts_sorted.txt 

It also includes the JavaScript file to reformat any new facts. If you dont mind, give me a follow on github too!

Comment: OMG @alec wilson you are AMAZING! I definitely did give you a follow on github. Sadly since i was hosting on glitch all those facts broke it LOL. I was using repl.it but the link are too big and i wanted it to be simple for my teacher. What my plan is is to just host it on repl.it then embed the repl.it page onto a glitch page so i can still have the domain factgen.glitch.me so yea...Thanks you so much!

Comment: NVM lol the page is fine. Just the syntax highlighting is broken as heck

Comment: Its finished! Btw i gave credit on the bottom footer. [https://factgen.glitch.me/](https://factgen.glitch.me/) is where you can go to find the generator. Now i just hope my teacher will actually use this. I am also gonna upload it to github later.

Comment: That’s awesome! Glad I could help!

Comment: could you please open an issue on my github repo? I will explain why after its opened. I'm Benjamin-0-Dover btw

Comment: Sure, I did it is #3

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry if I'm not understanding your code properly but from my understanding the first code block, the NodeJS is sending a file on the root url. That root file is what you want to alert this "random fact"

However, the random fact data is stored in `var fact = require("random-fact")`

NodeJS is a JavaScript runtime environment. Meaning a place to execute JavaScript code, OUTSIDE the browser and in the server. NodeJS isn't like vanilla JS where you have access to the BOM and DOM.

However, with express you can set up what's called an endpoint. That endpoint will send the data on each request to each route which you can set up on the front end.

First off, I'm assuming the `fact()` function returns some data. We'll set up an endpoint:

```
app.get('/random-facts', (req, res) => res.send(fact()));
```

whenever we send a get request to `/random-facts` it'll execute the function and hopefully get what you want

On the frontend we need to do what's called an AJAX request. Where you send a request to the API. Like you do in your browser when you type `www.google.com` you send a get request. AJAX request can get more sophisticated with just `GET` requests but that's for something else.

We'll do that with JS using the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

On your html you can do

```
<script>
fetch('http://localhost:3000/random-facts')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => alert(data));
</script>
```

This is probably a bit more advanced than what you know but I hope this helps

Comment: "This is probably a bit more advanced than what you know but I hope this helps" yes, yes it is. Honestly i just started javascript yesterday so its gonna take me a minute for this. Thanks though!